# Column widget isn't contracting

Tags: flutter

I have a container in a stack widget. the container contains a column. I'm trying to align the container to the bottom center of the app. So the pink background color should only take up the space of its child.
For some reason, it's taking up the entire height of the app. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      children: [
...Other Children
        Container(
          color: Colors.pink,
          child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, children: [Text('hey')]),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: set `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min`, property of Column

Comment: @neuromancer Perfect! Can u post as an answer so that I can accept

Comment: Yeah glad i can be of help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min`, property of Column, so your column contracts to the total size of its children

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question --and my understanding--, this is what you want to achieve:

[image: Goal]

The only problem with your code is that you put the `color: Colors.pink` values inside the parent `Container` of the `Column` widget.

To achieve position like the image above, add the `color: Colors.pink` values inside the `children` of the `Column` itself

```
Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            children: [
              // ...Other Children...
              Container(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, 
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.pink,
                      child: Text('hey'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
```